# Grid and other controls in the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a number of controls on a view and they are strongly typed to the Model

```
@ModelType  CalendarModels
```

So I can move data from and to the controller like this

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Current_Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", New With {.id = "inputMaintDate", .class = "form-control", .type = "date"})
```

I also need to add a Grid into the mix and that is looking for a list - in a separate view this works

```
@ModelType  List(Of MaintenanceWeb.MaintGrid)


@Html.Grid(Model).AutoGenerateColumns
```

But I have tried every which way (far too many to list) to find a method to get a grid into the view and also access the response in the controller, but nothing seems to work.

What is the best practice for this type of scenario?

Comment: Grid is not an input. It doesn't post anything back to your controller, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Hi Ataravati - the grid will have buttons and post back the selected ID from one of the columns. The main problem is getting the two different data types to work with the same Model. Managed this with a drop down list, but can't find any way so far with a grid!

Comment: You need to post more code in order to explain clearly what your problem is.

Comment: Use a view model containing properties for both models (`CalendarModels` and `List(Of MaintenanceWeb.MaintGrid)`)

Comment: I have tried a number of variations of that, including Tuple, but still keep hitting the proverbial brick wall. Can you post some example code of how that could work?

Answer (score 0):

I know I tried a variation of this that did not work, but this would appear to do the job

Controller:

```
Private MaintModel As New CalendarModels
Private DataModal As New List(Of MaintGrid)

Function Index() As ActionResult
    Try


        Return View(Tuple.Create(MaintModel, DataModal))
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return SystemError()
    End Try
End Function
```

View:

```
@ModelType  Tuple(Of CalendarModels, List(Of MaintGrid))
```

Change the markup for the controls using the first model

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) Model.Item1.Current_Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", New With {.id = "inputMaintDate", .class = "form-control", .type = "date"})
```

And, for the grid:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Item2).AutoGenerateColumns
```

I have yet to wire everything up and may hit other brick walls there, but managed to get over the first hurdle :-)

Comment: This will never work because you cannot post back a `Tuple`. Use a view model containing 2 properties, one for `CalendarModels` and one for `List(Of MaintenanceWeb.MaintGrid)`

Comment: Just create a view model with 2 properties - e.g. `public class MyViewModel { public CalendarModels Calendar { get; set; } public List<MaintGrid> Grid { get; set; } }` and in the model use `@model MyViewModel` and then generate the controls using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Calendar.Current_Date)` etc

Comment: Brilliant solution - changed the grid to ajax and that is causing other unrelated issues, but that does appear to be the answer. Do you want to enter it as an answer and I can mark it up?

Comment: Just edit your own answer and then accept to to close this out:)